# Finding all operators that preserve a function

Tags: functions, operator-theory, symmetry

I'm not even sure what field of math this would be, and Googling "symmetry" and "functions" doesn't reveal what I'm looking for.

Basically I want to find all $\{\hat{A}\}$ other than the identity operator for a *particular* $\psi$ such that

$$\hat{A}\psi = \psi$$

Is this generally possible?

(I mean, if I wanted to get more specific I could say $\hat{A}$ is a bounded linear operator and $\psi$ is normalized and so on... but I just need a starting point for this kind of problem.)

**EDIT:** I'll try to give a little more information on why/what I'm trying to do here.  Basically, I'm trying to extract symmetries from a function (like a wavefunction if you're familiar with physics) in order to reduce the information necessary to represent it.

For example, consider a spherically symmetric function $f$.  One way to represent it is in the Cartesian basis as $$f(x,y,z) = e^{-\left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)}$$

However, if you recognize that some kind of rotation operator applied to this function leaves it unchanged, you can rewrite it in the basis of spherical coordinates as:

$$f(r) = e^{-r^2}$$

Thus a function of 3 dimensions has been reduced to a function of 1 dimension by extracting a symmetry from the system.  I'm trying to identify *all* such operators, so I can change the basis of the function into one that gives it a minimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be *a lot* of these operators. For instance, if $\psi = (1,0)^T$, then $\hat A$ of the form

$$
\hat A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix}
$$

for any $x,y$ will work.

In more generality, if you're asking this in a vector space, let $\psi, e_2, e_3, \dots$ be a basis, then as long as $\hat A \psi = \psi$, you are completely free to choose $v_j = \hat A e_j$ however you want. There are a *lot* of such choices.